# How to print out each bytes' contents in a 4-byte int

Tags: c++, linux, byte, endianness

I designed a C++ code for checking machine's endian. 
It works well. But, it cannot print out each bytes' contents in a 4-byte int.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool f()
{
    int a = 1;
    char *p = (char*)&a;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i)
            cout << "p[" << i << "] is " << hex << *p++ << "   ";
    cout << endl ;
    p -= 4;
    if (*p == 1) return true ; // it is little endian
    else return false;  // it is big endian
}

int main()
{
    cout << "it is little endian ? " << f() << endl ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

output:

```
 p[0] is    p[1] is    p[2] is    p[3] is
 it is little endian ? 1
```

Why the output is empty ?

thanks

Comment: I hate hate hate hate `cout` streams when it comes to number formatting.  I'm sure there is a c++ appropriate way someone will explain, but I always fall back to the good ol' `printf()` function.  I don't know what hex is, but you'd be looking for something like `printf("p[%d] %04x\n", i, *p++);`

Comment: @jedwards, `hex` makes numbers print out in hexadecimal. The reason the "good ol' printf" isn't so good anymore is because it's not type safe. Go ahead if you have one that is; at least you'll get catchable and discernible errors.

Comment: The thing is, most modern compilers understand `printf`. It's outside the normal C++ type system, but regardless they can figure out what types it's expecting and generate warnings accordingly.

Comment: @duskwuff, That's true. `printf` is one of the more popular C concepts.

Comment: I wish Bjarne would have defined the stream manipulators to be a little more friendly to C programmers. Something like `std::cout << std::fmt("%x") << i << std::endl`

Comment: @user315052: not the worst idea, but would be slightly less efficient than the current approach since it would require a little more work at run-time. In your case, a string determines the desired type, but with `std::hex`, it's the type which does. So ideally, that type is used to invoke an overload decided at compile time.

Comment: @chris, @duskwuff: this is why I can't want for c++11 to be widely supported enough that type safe `printf` is common. it could even be implemented in a way that supports non-POD types (like `std::string`) :-)

Comment: @EvanTeran: yeah, the other wish list for me is to allow string literals to specialize templates, to get that compile time goodness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is that the type of `*p` is `char`, so the stream attempts to print the value of it as an ASCII character (which is likely not the value of a visible character). If you cast it to an `int` you will get what you expect:

```
cout << "p[" << i << "] is " << hex << static_cast<int>(*p++) << "   ";
```

Comment: thanks, for a is 1, i got : p[0] is 1   p[1] is 0   p[2] is 0   p[3] is 0, but for a is a1b2c3d4, i got : p[0] is ffffffd4   p[1] is ffffffc3   p[2] is ffffffb2   p[3] is ffffffa1, why not 000000d4 ...  ? thanks .

Comment: ah, you got bitten by sign extension. try casting to `unsigned int`, I forget, but you may need to mask the sign extended bits as well: so either: `static_cast<unsigned int>(*p++)` or (static_cast<unsigned int>(*p++) & 0xff)`

Answer (score 0):

printf suggested is OK but also an alternative is using shift operators <<,>> to investigate individual bytes of the int.

Answer (score 0):

I coded the following to print every byte of an int array. Each int was 4 bytes long.
Hope this helps in some way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int length = 5;
    unsigned int* array = new unsigned int[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        array[i] = 16843009;
    for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
    int new_dividend=0,k=0,l=0;
        double bytevalue=0;
        int bits[32];
        int number=array[i];
        //Initializing
        for(int c=0;c<=31;c++)
        {
            bits[c]=0;
        }
        //convert to binary
        while(number!=1)
        {
            new_dividend=number/2;
            bits[k]=number%2;
            number=new_dividend;
            k++;
            }
        bits[k]=1;
        //Pad with zero if needed
        if(k!=31)
        {
            for(int ctr=k+1;ctr<=31;ctr++)
            {
                bits[ctr]=0;
            }
        }

    for(int counter=0;counter<=31;counter++)
{
    //Print value of each byte.Also Reset values after each bytevalue has been printed.
    if(l==8)
    {
        l=0;
        cout<<bytevalue;
        bytevalue=0;
    }
    //calculate value of each byte
    bytevalue=bytevalue+(pow(double(2),l))*bits[counter];
    ++l;
}
    if(l==8)
    {cout<<bytevalue;
    }
    }
     delete[] array;

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output = 11111111111111111111 for an array[i] = 16843009 where i may be any range.